# Connecting a Cisco 3750E Switch using putty

Tags: putty, switch

I'm trying to connect to a Cisco 3570E switch through the console using putty.

I have the following configurations on putty:

```
Serial line: COM1
Speed: 9600
Data bits: 8
Stop bits: 1
Parity: None
Flow Control: None
```

When I click "Open", I just see a black window with a green cursor. It doesn't react to any keys I press (including "Enter"), and there's no prompt. I've tried "XON/XOFF" for Flow Control, and it's the same.

How can I connect to the switch?

Comment: It's possible the console port has been disabled. Do you have a copy of the switch configuration?

Comment: I have the text file where I copied the switch configuration to. How can I check if the console port is disabled?

Comment: look for "line aux 0      no exec"

Comment: I don't see "line aux 0 no exec" in the switch config.

Comment: I seem to vaguely recall that you may need to press Enter multiple times to get an initial reaction.  (I know you said you tried pressing Enter.  Did you try pressing it 3-6 times in a row?)

Answer (score 0):

Here are [the instructions for connecting a Console port to a PC.](http://www-tss.cisco.com/eservice/compass/common/tasks/task_console_port_connect.htm)

If the cabling configuration is correct, it may be the COM port device setup.

From that page:

### Troubleshooting console port problems

#### SYMPTOM: No connection.

- Check your laptop's settings to see if COM1 is loaded.
- Click on Start > Settings > Control Panel. Within the Control Panel window, open the Systems icon. Choose the Device Manager tab, and ensure that COM1 is an option on the Ports drop-down list. If COM1 is missing, reboot your laptop and repeat this check. It should now appear.

#### SYMPTOM: No response from router once connected to router via console.

- Check to ensure you are using the correct cable (roll-over as opposed to straight through).

  Verify that HyperTerminal is configured to use the correct communications port.

#### SYMPTOM: Only getting garbage from the router.

Ensure HyperTerminal is setup using the correct speed -- 9600 Baud.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there is no connection. If the Cisco device was refusing the connection it would tell you "Connection Refused." In windows open the devicemanager > Ports (COM & LPT), specifically the little triangle next to it then look to see the COM port showing active traffic.